# How to disable NLog from sending emails when running MVC3 app on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nlog

Does anyone know how to disable the NLog application from sending out emails when running tests on the MVC3 application on localhost? I would like NLog to only send out emails when the application gets en error when deployed to the webserver. What would I have to write in order to accomplish that?

Thanks

Comment: @Yasser I've only asked like four questions and I've only goten like two correct answeres. I mean, shouldn't have to accept answers that aren't correct?

Comment: What settings do NLog use for sending e-mails? The regular system.net/mailSettings?

Comment: @SteenT I think it's called regular system.net settings yes :) Here is a link to the documentation I used for adding the mail service: http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Mail_target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try "disabling" the mail sending by changing the mail settings:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
                <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\whateverfolder"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

This will drop off the e-mails in a folder on your computer. This doesn't really stop the mails, but it stops them from being sent.

Also making it a lot easier to verify that e-mails are being "sent", if you're running manual or automated tests.

Comment: I'll accept this solution as a "temporary" solution, but I still would really appreciate if someone could help me with a real solution :)

Comment: I haven't worked with NLog, but could you remove that "Mail" target from the configuration file?

Comment: Of course I could, but then I wouldn't get any emails when web server hits an error :)

Comment: Well, I was thinking you could do it when running test on the local computer? But maybe I'm not understanding what it is you need.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [filters](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Filters) for this. You could use a [when-filter](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/When_filter) to filter messages for your mail target, if the server name is localhost. This assumes that you are requesting the sites with localhost. However you could use any [Layout renderer](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Layout_renderers) for the condition.

See an example config below, which works for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <targets>
  <target xsi:type="Mail" name="m" layout="${message}" subject="Log" 
          to="mail@domain.com" from="app@domain.com" body="${message}"
          smtpServer="localhost">
  </target>
 </targets>
 <rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Fatal" writeTo="m" >
    <filters>
      <when condition="equals('${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_NAME}','localhost')" action="Ignore" />
    </filters>
  </logger>
 </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Hi! As you probably can see I voted to remove my answer to my question. I simply was too eager answering the question as I had not tested my solution well enough. Anyway, so I was trying out your solution but I'm afraid it was without results. I simply copied your "filters" tag into my code which basically looks the same as yours, but as a result I got the yellow screen of death when compiling, complaining about the row "<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd">". It would be really awesome if you think that you could help me out with this :)

Comment: @MarcusÅberg Which version of NLog are you using? I used the latest NuGet packages. Do you have the NLog config in the web.config or in a separate NLog.config (like me)?

Comment: I'm running version 2.0 of NLog. I did have the NLog config in a separate file, but now it is all copied over to web.config, though it is exactly the same code :)